# onComplete fires too soon

Tags: dojo, xpages

When should onComplete fire?

In 8.5.2 it fires when the event has runned so If you set some values in the event they will reflect in the update that is executed using the XSP.partialGet.
But in 8.5.3 in all browsers execpt IE the onComplete event fires and is returned before the event that it should be doing oncomplete for.
Anybody seen this and perhaps have a solution for the problem?

Comment: It seams like the problem can be releated to the following error that I saw in the FF console TypeError: n.style is undefined
/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js
Line 14

Comment: The problem was in some part of the dojo standby dialog widget 
http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2012/standby-custom-control-what-does-it-do I will investigate more and update this topic.

Comment: If you get invalid argument dojo.js line 14 then you have some code that is using dojo.style and that function gives problems in IE browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the standby Widget. an new version will be published.
the n.style problem in dojo.js is when you try to add stuff to dojo.body()