# How to apply standby.show to the full body of html

Tags: dojo

I would like to know how to apply standby.show to the full body of html?

I tried applying  it but it does not work.

regards 
Clement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the target of the standby widget to document body.

```
require([ "dojox/widget/Standby" ], function(st) {
                var standby = new st({
                    id : "StandyBy1",
                    target : dojo.body(),
                });
                document.body.appendChild(standby.domNode);
                standby.startup();
                standby.show();

            });
```

Comment: Thanks I am using dojo 1.8. I changed to "target:win.body()" with dojo/_base/window in require to load module. I tried your code with little modifications and I end up with error, "TypeError: n.style is undefined". This error points to line 15 in dojo.js.

Comment: Looks to be a problem with older dojo, and adding to the body tag.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478420/oncomplete-fires-too-soon

Comment: I have a script that does not work well, although I have added zIndex:100. The error says "TypeError: node is null" in jsFiddle.  Please refer to [link](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/8KHsm/3/). Please advise why it is not working.

Comment: In standby4body remove the quotes that surround win.body()

Comment: but if there is a popup or dialog then the standby widget is behind the dialog/popup. What should be done so that the target includes the dialog/popup body as well?

Answer (score 0):

At first have a look here for using standby : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/widget/Standby.html#dojox-widget-standby

then i would say it's enough to set the width and height of your div ( you use a div for this right? ) up to 100% to make it fit to the screen.

For more information and better support add some code to your post!

Regards

Comment: thanks I had already read it but I prefer simple and straight forward like "whole body" without having to define the dimension. Thanks again.