# How to apply dojox.widget.Standby.show to the full body of html when it has popover

Tags: dojo

I referred this link [How to apply standby.show to the full body of html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305983/how-to-apply-standby-show-to-the-full-body-of-html), and used below code , but the standby is applied to the full body behind popover. I wanted the standBy widget to overlay the popover as well.

```
 require([ "dojox/widget/Standby" ], function(st) {
            var standby = new st({
                id : "StandyBy1",
                target : dojo.body(),
            });
            document.body.appendChild(standby.domNode);
            standby.startup();
            standby.show();

        });
```

The popover has the button to make ajax call. So the efffect should be on full body including popover when the ajax call is made.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append `standby.domNode` as last element in your body tag and set an higher `zIndex` property for `standby` object, this will allow it to be higher in the stack order.

So from your code this line is wrong:

```
document.body.appendChild(standby.domNode);
```

Reference to `dojo/place` can be find [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/place.html).

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sev6tcns/6/

```
require(["dojox/widget/Standby", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/dom-construct"], function(Standby, win,domConstruct) {
  var standby = new Standby({
    id: "StandyBy1",
    target: dojo.body(),
    zIndex: 1000
  });
  domConstruct.place(standby.domNode, win.body());
  standby.startup();
  standby.show();
});
```